# Selecting closest campaign to qualified lead date and making the rest null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have an issue where one campaign is closest to several marketing qualified leads that have the same campaign name and campaign touch date. I have attached a photo of two tables, I'm trying to change the blue table into the green table, where only the top associated campaign is brought in while the rest are null. I attempted using partitions but did not end up with the output I wanted. Any recommendations?

```html
 select *,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by mql_lead_contact_id order by mql_days_after_last_touched_capture_campaign asc) as number,
    lag(mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_name,1) over (partition by mql_lead_contact_id order by mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date asc) as previous_campaign_name,
    lag(mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date,1) over (partition by mql_lead_contact_id order by mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date asc) as previous_campaign_date,
    date_diff(mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date, lag(mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date,1) over (partition by mql_lead_contact_id order by mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date asc), day)
        as campaign_date_day_difference,
    case when 
        date_diff(mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date, lag(mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date,1) over (partition by mql_lead_contact_id order by mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_date asc), day)
        = 0 then 'true' else 'false'end
        as same_campaign_date 

FROM TableA
where mql_lead_contact_id='123'
order by mql_days_after_last_touched_capture_campaign
```

[image] dates

Comment: Hi OP, can you please elaborate the condition on identifying which is the top associated campaign among the other campaigns? This is to properly replicate your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own question. I just needed to use below approach:

```
case when first_value(mql_date) over (partition by mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_name order by mql_date) = mql_date then mql_last_touched_capture_campaign_name else null end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).